# iOS Swift: TableViewCell not being drawn properly

Tags: ios, swift

I'm getting a weird bug where the tableViewCell footers are not being drawn properly on launch. But once the cells are recycled they appear as intended. Here is a screen recording (notice how the top cell footer appears after being recycled): https://www.dropbox.com/s/tw1le35ppaim3yb/Recording.mov?dl=0

ViewController.swift

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.registerClass(TableCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    view.addSubview(tableView)
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cell:TableCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as TableCell
  let data = items[indexPath.row]
  cell.date.text = data.creationDate.description
  return cell
}
```

TableCell.swift

```
class TableCell: UITableViewCell {

    let date = UILabel()

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        contentView.addSubview(date)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        superview?.layoutSubviews()        
        date.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, frame.width, 30)
    }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't you put `date.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, frame.width, 30)` before `contentView.addSubview(date)` ? Why is it in `layoutSubviews()`?

Comment: Have you tested on a device?

Comment: The frame doesn't exist until layoutSubviews is called, as far as I can tell. It will also redraw the frame this way if the view changes. Tested on device and got the same result.

Comment: I suggest putting it in `override func drawRect(_ rect: CGRect)` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my overriding `layoutSubviews` I didn't call `super.layoutSubviews()`.